# how to export to excel and csv format in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

i need to export to excel and csv format in jasper reports.
    for excel i tried by creating custom class (using api)but it is not exporting, the thing is save and cancel popup window is coming with file type unkown..

any idea why it is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use as a [JRXlsExporter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRXlsExporter.html) to export to XSL and a [JRCsvExporter](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRCsvExporter.html) for CSV.

There should be no need to create a custom class in most cases.

**Edit**

The class is stored inside the jar poi-3.5-FINAL-20090928.jar, which should be locate in your "iReportInstallationFolder"\modules\ext\

For me it's `C:\Program Files\Jaspersoft\iReport-3.7.4\ireport\modules\ext\`

The name could be different but should be poi-3.5-FINAL-*.jar.

Make it is included in your classpath and you should be fine.

You can download the jar from [Apache Poi](http://poi.apache.org) home page.

Here is a link to the jar I have from their site http://archive.apache.org/dist/poi/release/bin/poi-bin-3.5-FINAL-20090928.tar.gz

Comment: @Gordon.. i got the exception  like "Uncaught exception thrown in one of the service methods of the servlet: InvestorConfirmServlet. Exception thrown : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle".. i put .jar file also in the classpath. but even it throws error...

Comment: Do you mean tell the report to export to xsl? Please edit you answer.

Comment: by using JRXlsExporter it is not exporting, the thing is save and cancel popup window is coming with file type unkown..

Comment: Have you tried exporting your file with a different exporter? You report may be empty.

Comment: data is there..can you give some example? i code is like this..reportExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
    reportExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, reportStream); where reportStream is object of "ByteArrayOutputStream()". contenttype is "response.setContentType("application/xls");"

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using JRCsvExporter, the following code may be useful. Giving some sample structure.

Spring Framework Service class (CSVExportService.java):

```
public JasperPrint getRawData(String empIds) {

JasperPrint jp = null;
String reportName = "Employee Report";

// use your own method to get empList
// eg: List<Employee> empList = empServiceClass.findByEmpIds(empIds);
JRDataSource jrDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(empList);

// build your report 
DynamicReportBuilder dynamicReportBuilder = new DynamicReportBuilder();
dynamicReportBuilder.setAllowDetailSplit(false);
// configure your report with few more options here

// create columns
ColumnBuilder columnBuilderName = ColumnBuilder.getNew();
columnBuilderName.setTitle("Emp Name");
columnBuilderName.setWidth(300);
columnBuilderName.setFixedWidth(true);
columnBuilderName.setColumnProperty("name", String.class.getName());
dynamicReportBuilder.addColumn(columnBuilderName.build());

DynamicReport dynamicReport = dynamicReportBuilder.build();

jp = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(dynamicReport, new ClassicLayoutManager(), jrDataSource, new HashMap<String, Object>());
return jp;
}
```

Spring Framework Controller Class:

```
public void exportToCSV(@PathVariable String empIds){
  JasperPrint jp = null;
  jp = csvExportService.getRawData(empIds);
  response.setContentType("text/csv");
  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="EMPRawData.csv");
  OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
  JRCsvExporter exporterCSV = new JRCsvExporter();
  exporterCSV.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jp);
  exporterCSV.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, out);
  exporterCSV.exportReport();

  out.flush();
}
```

Comment: What if i don't have a response (HttpServletResponse) on my application?
how do i create the file?

Answer (score 0):

```
    JRCsvExporter exporter = new JRCsvExporter();
    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleWriterExporterOutput(new FileOutputStream(new File(output1))));
    SimpleCsvExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimpleCsvExporterConfiguration();
    //configuration.setWriteBOM(Boolean.TRUE);
    exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
    exporter.exportReport();
```

Kindly use this code .its working fine

Comment: Why the fifth row is commented?