# I'm trying to develop excel page using jasper report

Tags: java, excel, jasper-reports

I am working on Jasper report. I try to generate excel file but I am getting exception my code below.

```
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("C:\\jasper files\\report1.jrxml"); 
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap(), new JREmptyDataSource());

JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter(); 
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint); 
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, "sample1.xls"); 
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.TRUE); 
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE); 
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE); 
exporterXLS.exportReport();
```

Exception is`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the Apache POI jar in your CLASSPATH, Apache POI jar is needed for excel export, the message you are getting is it cannot find the POI class.

You can obtain POI jar from http://poi.apache.org/

Also see [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3733775/352672) for a similar answer to your question.